# How to use same route guard for different routes that differ in authorization logic

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router-guards, canactivate

For my Angular 6 project, I have one canactivate AuthGuard to load ComponentA.

I want to know can I use the same AuthGuard for component B where it's the authorization logic is exactly opposite to component A?

Let's say the logic to authorize component A as follows

- Get summary items from API service HTTP GET call
- Iterate on the items and check the activationStatus. If activation status is 'ACTIVE' return true
- If no summary items are returned and activation status is not 'ACTIVE', return false and just show the login page.

My requirement is load component B is exactly opposite to above.

- Show component B If no summary items are returned and activation status is not 'ACTIVE', do not load the component and just show the login page
- If summary items are present and activation status is 'ACTIVE' just show login page.

Existing `auth.guard.ts` for component A:

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
 
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>
{
    return this.checkAuthorization();
}
checkAuthorization():Observable<boolean>{

    let hasActiveSummary:boolean=false;

    return this.apiService.getSummary(url)
    .pipe(
      map((data:any) => {
        console.log("Summary list:", data);
          if(data.length > 0){
            for (let i=0; i< data.length; i++) {
              if(data[i].activationStatus ==='ACTIVE') {
                hasActiveSummary=true;
                return true;
              }
            }
          }
          if(!hasActiveSummary){
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
          }
      })
    )
}
```

I would like to know can I use the same auth guard? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`canActivate` method has `state` property which is of type [RouterStateSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterStateSnapshot). You can make a decision based on `state.url` and just return the inverse of `hasActiveSummary` based on the route you are reaching.